# Actionscript/Animate - Fill in next array spot if this one is already filled

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

so I am working on a graphical calculator (bit more of a challenge than the basic windows one), and I want to be able to do the entire "math" in one textfield, just like typing in "5+3-5*11/3" and it gives you the solution when you press '='

I decided to make it with arrays of numbers and symbols, but I have no idea how to make it to fill the next array if this one already is used:

```
var numbers:Array = new Array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
var actions:Array = new Array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
```

I am using split to split the numbers I input with symbols, and I want the numbers to be placed in the arrays. Example: I type in 555+666 and then I need to have something like

```
if (numbers[0] = "") {numbers[0] = 555}
else if (numbers[1] = "") {numbers[1] = 555}
else if.....
```

Know what I mean?
Pretty hard to describe...
something like... When I type in a number, if the numbers[0] is already filled, go fill in numbers[1], if numbers[1] is filled, go to numbers[2] etc

Comment: Surely this is solved? Use a `for` loop where `var i : int = 0` and if `i < numbers.length` then should increment `i++`... now inside the For loop you can do `if (numbers[i] == "") { numbers[i] = int(555) } ` and that's it...!! (anything not **==** to `""` will be auto skipped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to implement is the [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). In actionscript3 arrays are dynamic, not fixed size, that means you can add elements to the array without concern about capacity (at least in your case).

```
const array:Array = new Array();
trace(array.length);             // prints 0 
array.push(1);
array.push(2);
trace(array.length);             // prints 2
```

I suggest using "push" and "pop" methods of Array/Vector, since it's much more natural for such task. Using those methods will simplify your implementation, since you'll get rid of unnecessary checks like

```
if (numbers[1] == "") {...}
```

and replace it just with:

```
numbers.push(value);
```

and then to take a value from the top:

```
const value:String = numbers.pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if I agree with @Nbooo and the Reverse Polish Notation
However Vectors may have a fixed length.

**This is not an answer but just an example** (if the length of Your Array must be defined):

```
//Just for information..
var numbs:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(10,true); 
var count:uint = 1;
for (var i in numbs){
    numbs[i] = count++
}
trace(numbs);

// If You try to add an element to a Vector,
// You will get the following Error at compile time :
/*
RangeError: Error #1126: Cannot change the length of a fixed Vector.
    at Vector$double/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::push()
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

*/
numbs.push(11);
// Will throw an Error #1126
trace(numbs);
```

If You use this code to update a fixed Vector, this will **not** throw an ERROR :

```
numbs[4]=11;
trace(numbs);
```

Output :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,11,6,7,8,9,10
// length is 10, so no issue...
```

If You consider the performance between Arrays and vectors check this reference : [Vector class versus Array class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3a0f5f19124318fc87b-7fff.html)

I hope this may be helpful.

[EDIT]

I suggest you to check at those links too :

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Arrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Associative arrays, maps, and dictionaries](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Vectors and ByteArrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals)

[/EDIT]

Best regards.
Nicolas.

Comment: could I please ask you something on priv chat about actionscript? Don't want to waste a question spot on stackoverflow for something so simple, but can't find the solution anywhere..
Link to a chatroom I opened: http://www.e-chat.co/room/174323

Comment: Sure, the vector can be fixed, I just supposed that in this situation for this question the non-fixed vector will be more suitable. Of course that was just an opinion.

Comment: @Nbooo : That's the reason why I said : "This is not an answer but just an example" ;)